# How to split a large gzip file into smaller gzip files without uncompressing it first?

Tags: linux, gzip

Is there a way to split a large gzip file into smaller gzip files without using `zcat`?

```
zcat large.bed.gz| split --numeric-suffixes - -b 7M --filter='gzip > $FILE.gz' large.part.
```

Comment: Yes there is, but - assuming the issue is speed and not a substitute way to decompress the files - the result won't handle like gzip files until recombined. What is your goal here?

Comment: @davidgo the goal: split a huge gzip file into 10,000 smaller gzip files, run an script on each small file and then merge.

Comment: Why the prohibition on zcat? (There are alternatives to this but AFAIK you will have to decompress the archive to split them and have individually accessible files.  Also, is it reasonable to assume this is a text file? It occurs to me your current solution -  can break a file in the middle of a line....

Comment: @davidgo it’s a CSV file. I want to avoid the zcat to save time.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question (taking into account the goal of saving time rather then substituting zcat for something else - which can be done) is **this is not possible**.

The issue is that the compressed output of a gzip file will be of varied length depending on the input and this is not easily predicted, so there are no obvious boundaries on which to split the file.

Also, is the command you advised the actual commmand you are using?  If so it is broken as it will split the file in arbitrary positions, not line boundaries.  You should use something like "-l XXXXX" - where XXXXX is a number of lines, rather then "-b 7M" being an block size.

You have not provided sufficient information for us to advise further work-arounds, but if you have control over how the .gz file is generated you may be able to split the file into pieces as its being created - this is fairly common and there are many strategies that can be deployed depending on how its created.

Comment: Good catch on the -l. Why does it have a stand alone hyphen? Between the -l and --numeric-suffixes?

Comment: Not 100% certain and not near a PC to check  (split is not a command I use with any regularity) but most likely it means "take input from stdin" - which is a common Linux/Unix convention and makes syntactic sense here as its input is the output of to zcat stream.